# Celery in production raise ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'celery'

Tags: django, celery, gunicorn, production

In developement all is good, app starts without any problems. However, in production, Gunicorn can't start due ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'celery'

Celery is installed properly

```
>>> from celery import Celery
>>> print(Celery)
<class 'celery.app.base.Celery'>
```

already tried changing file name to anything other than celery.py - did not help

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things you can try to resolve the issue:

1. Check if the Python version used in production matches the one used in development. If it's different, make sure that Celery is installed for the correct version of Python.
2. Check if the virtual environment is activated when running the app in production. The virtual environment should contain all the required packages, including Celery.
3. Check if the Celery module is installed in the correct location. The module should be located in the site-packages directory of the Python environment.
4. Try to run the command pip show celery in the environment where you are running the app in production. This command will show you the location of the Celery package and the version number. Make sure that it matches the version installed in your development environment.
5. Try to run your app with the following command: python -c "import celery". This will check if the Celery module can be imported without any issues.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).